# How to enable people to remotely view and interact with a program

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, streaming, remote, teamviewer

I have a piece of software (a .exe) that I run locally, and I want multiple people to be able to remotely view and interact with it in particular.

The usual approach would be to start it up on my Desktop and run TeamViewer on a section of my screen to have people interact with it.

I'm wondering if there's a way to do it "virtually" where I do not have to actually see the software running on my computer? It just runs in the background on my computer, but nevertheless everyone can remotely see it and interact with it.

I have Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

You could install or set up a device with a Windows Server OS, then use [Remote Desktop Session Host](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-roles#:%7E:text=The%20Remote%20Desktop%20Session%20Host,by%20using%20the%20web%20client.) to archive that. However you must [pay for a license](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc725933(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for each user